# Get progress value of PullRefreshProgressControl in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp

How can i get the progress value in code?
Here's the XAML:

```
 <ptr:PullToRefreshBox x:Name="ptrBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" RefreshInvoked="ptrBox_RefreshInvoked">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel Name="SPMain" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <ptr:PullToRefreshBox.TopIndicatorTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ptr:PullRefreshProgressControl Name="ProgressPTR" Progress="300" PullToRefreshText="Pull to refresh" ReleaseToRefreshText="Release"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ptr:PullToRefreshBox.TopIndicatorTemplate>
        </ptr:PullToRefreshBox>
```

Comment: What progress value?

Comment: I want to get the amount of pixels that the user has pulled down from, kinda like a slider value

Comment: What is the `PullToRefreshBox` you are using?

Comment: i used a library called PullToRefresh.UWP.

Comment: what i want is a way for me to tell how much has the user "pulled" before invoking the refresh method. i want to blur a photo depending on how much the user has pulled from the top. the more the user has stretched or pulled down, the more intense the blur gets. i already have the code for blurring an image ready i just want a way to tell how much has the user pulled

Answer (score 2):

Just write this

```
Progress="{Binding}"
```

in place of `Progress="300"`

Comment: NOTE: Use library PullToRefresh.UWP